# Delete empty rows in SAS

Tags: sas

I have data set that contains empty cells. It looks like

```
 Year    Volume    ID    
 2000    999       LSE
 2001    .         LSE
 .       555       LSE
 2008    .         NYSE
 2010    1099      NYSE
```

I need to delete the row that contains empty cells. The output should look like this

```
 Year    Volume    ID    
 2000    999       LSE
 2000    1099      NYSE
```

I tried following code

```
data test;
set data;
if volume = " . " then delete;
if year= " . " then delete;
run;
```

But output file has 0 observations and SAS gives me

```
    NOTE: Character values have been converted to numeric values at the       
places given by (Line):(Column).
```

Also I tried

```
options missing = ' ';
data test;
set data;
if missing(cats(of _all_)) then delete;
run;
```

But its not working as well.

I just want to delete the rows with empty cells.
Anyone can help me to solve this issue ? Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: As Joe mentioned, your code above should still work with the automatic conversion of character to numeric. There must be something else going on. Is there anything else in your data step?

Answer (score 3):

`Options Missing` only affects how things are printed or converted when going numeric -> character.  In this case you have numerics, so it accomplishes nothing.

Your first code sample is mostly correct- at least, when I try it, it works.  `" . "` is not really right, but it will convert (as the note says) to missing since none of those characters are a number.

The proper way to do this is one of the two:

```
data have;
input Year    Volume    ID    $;
datalines;
 2000    999       LSE
 2001    .         LSE
 .       555       LSE
 2008    .         NYSE
 2010    1099      NYSE
 ;;;;
 run;

data want;
  set have;
  if year = . then delete;
  if volume =  . then delete;
run;
```

or

```
data want;
  set have;
  if missing(year) then delete;
  if missing(volume) then delete;
run;
```

[`missing`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000509996.htm) returns true if the variable is missing (which includes 28 total values, but `.` is the most common).

A better way to do more than one is to use the [`nmiss`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245920.htm) or `cmiss` functions (`nmiss` for numbers, `cmiss` for character or mixed type).

```
data want;
  set have;
  if nmiss(year,volume) = 0;
run;
```

That will return the number of missing values, which you can then test for whatever value you are looking for (in this case, zero values).  You could even do:

```
data want;
  set have;
  if nmiss(of _NUMERIC_) = 0;
run;
```

where `_NUMERIC_` is all numeric variables.  (`of` is needed for variable lists like this to tell SAS to expect a list.)

---

Your second doesn't work, by the way, because it's catting the ID variable together with the others.  You could have seen this by looking at the value of that `cats` (ie, assign it to a variable).  You could have said

`if cats(of _all_) = ID then delete;`

but as several of us have shown that's probably inferior to the simpler solutions using `nmiss`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a subsetting `if nmiss()` by checking the variables that must be populated:

```
data test;
   set data;
   if nmiss(year,volume)=0 ;
run;
```

**Edit:** This works if  `year` and `volume` is numeric, if it is string, you can use the `cmiss()`  function.

Comment: thanks @Bendy, but it doesnt work... there are 0 obs in output T.T

Comment: Check if your year/volume variables are numeric...if they're character then use `cmiss()` as Joe mentioned

Comment: @Bendy: I edited in your comment, please check whether that is ok for you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use quotes with numeric variables, e.g.:

```
if volume = .  then delete;
```

Other option that works for either character or numeric:

```
if missing(volume) then delete;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `where` clause in the set statement here as well:

```
data new_dataset;
 set old_dataset (where = (volume is not missing or year is not missing));
run;
```

I always enjoy using the `is not missing` syntax because it seems too much like writing normal English to work